# Use Athena ODBC driver with credential_source Ec2InstanceMetadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, odbc, amazon-athena

We are currently trying to set up Athena access between two accounts. The goal is that the EC2 instance role from one account assumes a specific role from a different AWS account that grants access to its Athena.

Using `Instance Profile` authentication in the driver does not work because we couldn't find a way to configure the preferred role.

If `IAM Profile` is used instead, the Athena ODBC driver throws an error:

```
FAILED!
Simba DriverIAMSupport (8600) Connection Error: No AWS Profile found:
```

The error message is misleading because the driver definitely finds the profile. Querying Athena using this profile via CLI works fine. Connecting Athena with `source_profile` attribute or using `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` also works.

This is how the profile config looks like:

```
[profile athena]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam:123456789:role/athena-read-role
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
region = eu-central-1
```

Tested with:

- Athena ODBC driver version: 1.1.6 (32 & 64 bit)
- Windows Server 2012 &
  Windows Server 2016

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-metadata.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/setting-global-credential_source.html#setting-credential_source-alternatives